# Laravel Inserir dados em uma tabela e usar o mesmo id para preencher outra

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5

estou iniciando no Laravel e estou com um problema relacionado a inserção de dados em duas tabelas do mysql... explicando melhor seria o seguinte:
Tenho uma tabela chamada questionarios onde tenho apenas ID e Descricao e uma outra tabela chamada enunciados onde tenho o ID, uma questão do tipo string e um outro campo chamado questionarios_id, e tenho um formulario onde eu preencho os seguintes campos: descricao do questionario e questão.
O que ocorre é que na hora que eu tento inserir no banco ao chegar na tabela enunciados o valor questionarios_id não é preenchido ocorrendo um erro, gostaria de saber se tem como eu pegar o id inserido na minha tabela questionarios e utiliza-lo para preencher o campo questionarios_id da minha tabela enunciados

segue os codigos:

model Questionario:

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Questionario extends Model
{   
  public $timestamps = false;
  protected $fillable = array('descricao');

  public function enunciado(){
    return $this->hasMany('App\Enunciado');
  }

}
```

model Enunciado:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Enunciado extends Model
{

  public $timestamps = false;
  protected $fillable = array('questao');

  public function questionario(){
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Questionario');
  }
```

}

meu controller:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Questionario;
use App\Enunciado;
use App\Http\Requests\QuestionarioRequest;


class ControllerPrincipal extends Controller
{
    public function index(){
        return view('ViewFormulario');
}
public function enviar(QuestionarioRequest $request){

    Questionario::create($request->all());
    Enunciado::create($request->all());
    return redirect()->action('ControllerPrincipal@index');
}
```

}

o erro que esse codigo da ao enviar o formualario é o seguinte:

```
QueryException in Connection.php line 647:
SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1364 Field 'questionarios_id' doesn't     have a default value (SQL: insert into `enunciados` (`questao`) values (teste))
```

Comment: o id é injetado no objeto que você acabou de criar, só precisaria colocar ele numa variavel e utilizar, ex: `$q = Questionario::create(.... ;` e depois pegar com o  $q->id`, mas to montando uma resposta mais completa.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

O comando Create não consegue fazer associações, e dificilmente o valor da chave estrangeira(no seu caso o `questionario_id`) virá por request, então eu não recomendaria usá-lo
nesse caso, mas mostrarei 2 opções, uma utilizando o Create e outra não, aí você decide qual a melhor para você.

Uma observação, sua pergunta foi sobre como pergar o ID, o ID é injetado no objeto que você acabou de criar.

### Com Create

Com o create você precisaria injetar o id do **Questionario** que você acabou de criar, no **Enunciado**(como `questionario_id`), isso por meio de uma variavel temporária (que aqui estou chamando de `$filler`):

```
public function enviar(QuestionarioRequest $request){
    $filler = $request->all();
    $questionario = Questionario::create($filler);

    $filler['questionario_id'] = $questionario->id;
    Enunciado::create($filler);

    return redirect()->action('ControllerPrincipal@index');
}
```

### Sem Create

Sem o Create, pelo menos no caso do `Enunciado`, seria criando um novo Objeto `Enunciado`, o resultado é bem similar:

```
public function enviar(QuestionarioRequest $request){
    $questionario = Questionario::create($request->all());

    $enunciado = new Enunciado($request->all());
    $enunciado->questionario_id = $questionario->id;
    $enunciado->save();

    return redirect()->action('ControllerPrincipal@index');
}
```

#### Com associate (sem create)

Um outro caso é usando o associate, só trocaria a linha do id
**De:**

```
$enunciado->questionario_id = $questionario->id;
```

**Para:**

```
$enunciado->questionario()->associate($questionario);
```

Comment: Pliavi deu certo, era isso mesmo, testei o metodo com create!

Answer (score -2):

Cara,  eu achei isso num site gringo e resolveu meu problema sem precisar mexer em nada além dessa linha de comando. O melhor é que tu não vai precisar alterar seu banco de dados, criado com tanto suor.

Encontre a pasta config e abra o arquivo database.php. Lá, encontre o 'strict -> true no bloco do banco de  dados que você usa e altere o valor para false. BUM! A mágica acontece :)